# Is This A Correct Example Usage Of current_filter()?

Tags: hooks, php, filters

Is this a good example of usage of [`current_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter)?

```
<?php
add_filter("_my_filter", "common_function");
add_filter("_another_filter", "common_function");
function common_function(){
  $currentFilter = current_filter();
  switch ($currentFilter) {
    case '_my_filter':
      echo "Called by My Filter";
      break;
    case '_another_filter':
      echo "Called by another filter";
      break;
  }
}
```

So I am guessing `current_filter()` is used to get the name of the filter for which the current execution is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi **@Raj Sekharan**:

Looks good to me, but is wanting to know the current usage really your question or do you want to understand where `current_filter()` gets it's information from?

If the latter, here's basically what happens in all the different hook processing functions, e.g. `do_action()`, `apply_filters()`, `do_action_ref_array()`, `apply_filters_ref_array()` (***greatly*** simplified, of course):

```
<?php
function <process_hook>($hook, $value) {
  global $wp_filter, $wp_current_filter;
  $wp_current_filter[] = $hook;  // "Push" the hook onto the stack.
  $value = call_user_func($wp_filter[$hook]['function'],$value);
  array_pop($wp_current_filter);
  return $value;
}
```

Then all that `current_filter()` does is retrieve the last hook *"pushed"* onto the global `wp_current_filter` array, i.e.:

```
<?php
function current_filter() {
  global $wp_current_filter;
  return end( $wp_current_filter );
}
```

Comment: I read the source and figured the pushing and popping part out. I was wondering why would we need this function. Must be some good use case. 

I thought may be to help discover which hook is being processed when using the same filter function is hooked onto both.

Comment: Hi *@Raj Sekharan* - In that case you already answered your own question. There are some hooks where it's easier to route to a common function but sometimes you need to do something slightly differently depending on the hook. Here's an example of many hooks routing to one function (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472334/#3474234) and if there were a need to know which hooks them the current_filter() function would be useful indeed. BTW, I didn't know it existed until I read you question but I immediate saw how it could be useful in special cases.

Comment: Sidenote: `$wp_current_filter` does not work for the "all" hook, so you need to add your own logic to find out wether your hook function has been triggered by 'all' or another (concrete) hook. `$wp_current_filter` will always contain the concrete hook name, never 'all'.

Comment: *@hakre:* That is correct. OTOH using `all` really should be limited to debugging since it fires for (practically?) every hook.

Answer (score 0):

In general—yes, this is a valid usage. If I were you I would pass different functions to the different filters and abstract the common parts in other function(s).

This way any of your function will do exactly one thing.

Comment: Hi *@Nikolay* - Good to see you here. Nice to meet you in Savannah!

Comment: Could you explain why using the same function for multiple hooks is less desirable?